# How can I view the contents of a List in the Console?

Tags: c#

I have this variable:

```
public static List<Phrase> viewablePhrases;
```

I would like to see the contents logged in the console like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(App.viewablePhrases)
```

but this doesn't show me the contents.

Is there a way I can see the contents in my Console?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and use the debugger to examine the contents of the object.

Comment: What's `Phrase`?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to display the list, not the values of objects that you add to your list:

You should output the string values that cointains your `Phrase` object:

```cs
public static List<Phrase> viewablePhrases
{
   new Phrase(/* your constructor */)
   // other your Phrase objects
};
for(int i = 0; i < viewablePhrases.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(viewablePhrases[i].Value); // or other property instad of "Value"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write out each item in the list, e.g.

```
foreach(var phrase in viewablePhrases)
{
    Console.WriteLine(phrase.ToString());
}
```

This assumes that your `Phrase` class has a suitable override of `ToString()` that will return a readable string.